# SASS - Mixin not compiling

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to compile a mixin to generate font styles, but unfortunatly its not working. There are also other mixins which are working fine except this. Not able to find issue in this.

```
@mixin GenerateFontStyles($fs, $lh, $clr){
  font-size : $fs;
  line-height: $lh;
  color:$clr;
}

.body-copy{
  color:#e20074;
  @inlcude GenerateFontStyles(15px, 20px, #000);
}
```

Comment: Examine the output CSS. You will see that the `@inlcude` is there, meaning that SASS has not processed it. Or, run the page in FF, and you will see the error `Expected declaration but found ‘@inlcude’.  Skipped to next declaration.`.

Comment: I recommend naming your variables more descriptively. `$font-size` really doesn't take much more time to type than `$fs` and it makes your code more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last line has a spelling mistake.

```
@inlcude GenerateFontStyles(15px, 20px, #000);
```

changed to:

```
@include GenerateFontStyles(15px, 20px, #000);
```

Comment: This is what the "typo" close reason is for.